# Foundation button mixin throws error

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm trying to use the Foundation `button()` mixin in order to change the color of the button. I tried following the example in the docs:

```
@include button(
// $padding - Used to build padding for buttons Default: $button-med or rem-calc(12)
$padding,
// Background color. We can set $bg:false for a transparent background. Default: $primary-color.
$bg,
// If true, set to button radius which is $global-radius or explicitly set radius amount in px (ex. $radius:10px). Default:false.
$radius,
// We can set $full-width:true to remove side padding extend width. Default:false
$full-width,
// We can set $disabled:true to create a disabled transparent button. Default:false
$disabled
);
```

But my compiler complains that the mixin only takes 4 arguments. I can feed in four arguments, but none of them take the action I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameters as named parameters to the `@include()`. Like this:

```
@include button($padding: 4px, $bg: #1a1a1a, $radius: 3px, $full-width: false);
```

Also, the parameter names will depend on which version of Foundation you're using. Your example indicates you're using Foundation 5. Foundation 6 uses different parameter names.